# How to fetch particular column stored procedure from hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am trying to fetch user details from MYSQL database through the stored procedure using hibernate am getting:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'create_time' not found.

in MYSQL db I have taken timestamp data type for create_time
why?

**My stored procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `BIM`.`getUserDetailsSP`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`mariadb`@`%` PROCEDURE `getUserDetailsSP`(IN in_email VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT UserID, a.UserTypeID, b.UserTypeName,firstname,lastname,phone
    FROM BIM.UserDetailsV a 
    JOIN BIM.UserTypeDetailsV b ON a.UserTypeID = b.UserTypeID 
    WHERE a.email = in_email;
END$$

DELIMITER ;$$
```

**Hibernate**

```
try{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
            "CALL getUserDetailsSP(:email)")
            .addEntity(UserDTO.class)
            .setParameter("email", "bob@gmail.com");

        List result = query.list();
        for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
            UserDTO stock = (UserDTO)result.get(i);
            System.out.println(stock.getFirstName());
        }
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

**UserDTO**

```
public class UserDTO implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "j", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "j")
    @Column(name = "UserID")
    private long userID;

    @Column(name = "UserTypeID")
    private long userTypeID;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private Date create_time;

    @Column(name = "update_time")
    private Date update_time;
// getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of UserDTO.

Comment: in mysql db i have taken timestamp data type for create_time

Comment: Check what happens if you add create_time in the select statement of the procedure: `SELECT UserID, a.UserTypeID, b.UserTypeName,firstname,lastname,phone, create_time FROM...`

Comment: then email column not found i have tried buddy

Comment: Hibernate tries to map all of the columns in the entity from the returned resultset. So all of the fields in the entity that are marked with @Column has to be present in the select clause of the stored procedure.

Comment: yes, how to fetch particular column